# Об употреблении слов "только", "либо", "ни", "но"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат четыре карты одной масти: туз, король, дама, валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми либо только туза, либо только даму." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо даму; но не бери ни короля, ни валета.",
- указание "Возьми либо только короля, либо только даму." подразумевает указание "Возьми либо короля, либо даму."?

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно! ТОЛЬКО. I. частица.
1.
Не более как, всего лишь. Вещь стоит т. рубль. Ей т. пять лет. Ходит т. в кино. Это т. начало. Танцевала т. два танца. Всего т. год жил с женой. Ещё т. двенадцать часов! Т. его и видели (разг.;
не успел появиться, как уже исчез). //
Не ранее чем. Вернулся т. под утро. Уедет т. вечером.
***2.
Единственно, исключительно.*** Говорил т. о любви. Стремится т. к победе. Не любит т. вранья. Т. в деревне и отдыхаю. Люблю т. тебя. Не купил лишь т. из жадности.
3.
Употр. после местоимений, наречий, союзов для усиления, подчёркивания. Зачем т. я сюда приехала. Кому т. не рассказывал. Где т. не бывал.
4.
Придаёт выражению значение угрозы, предостережения; посмей, попробуй. Т. тронь! Т. проиграй! Т. ослушайся! II. союз.
1.
Однако, но. Хороша по-прежнему, т. располнела. Согласен уйти, т. не сейчас. Всё было хорошо, т. скучновато.
2.
Едва. Т. приехала, сразу заболела. Т. намекнули, а он обиделся. III. нареч.
Совсем недавно. Неопытный учитель: т. институт закончил. Ты, верно, т. проснулась. < Только бы, частица.
Выражает желательность или возможность какого-л. факта. Только бы не опоздать! Только бы поправилась от болезни! Только и..., что, частица.
***Единственно, исключительно.*** Только и думаю, что о детях. Только и всего, в зн. межд.
И больше ничего, и всё, и всё тут. Только-только, в зн. нареч. 1.
Совсем недавно. Только-только пришли домой. -2.
Едва, еле-еле. Денег хватило только-только на дорогу. Только что, в зн. нареч.
Совсем недавно. Солнце только что село. Он только что пришёл. Только что... не, частица.
Почти, немногого не хватает до чего-л. Его только что на руках не носят. Пустился догонять только что не бегом. Да и только; и только, в зн. частицы. Разг.
***Употр. для выражения ограничительного значения, подчёркивая категоричность высказывания. Ей нравится музыка и только***. Ходил на рыбалку, продрог да и только. Не только.., но и, в зн. союза.
Соединяет однородные члены предложения, из которых второй представляется более существенным, более значительным. Не только дети, но и взрослые любят играть в шашки. Разве только, что. в зн. союза.
Выражает допущение, возможность чего-л. Лишь только, в зн. союза. (присоединяет придаточную часть предложения, действие которой совершается непосредственно перед действием главной части).
Как только, едва. Лишь только вошёл в комнату, дети сразу подбежали к нему. Едва только (см. Едва). Как только (см. Как). Подумать только (см. Подумать).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.